# UIToolbar gradient fix

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitoolbar

I am using `UIToolbar` in my project for this lock screen. Everything is fine except the gradient on the `UIToolbar` is very short. I mean its height is not equal. I have attached the screen shot. I want the `UIToolbar`  to be like figure B.

Any idea how to achieve this.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing you can do is setting appearance for your `UIToolBar`:

```
UIImage *gradientImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"upperBar.png"]
                                resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4, 300, 10, 300)];
UIToolbar *toolbar = [UIToolBar appearance];
[toolbar setBackgroundImage:gradientImage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Where `upperBar.png` is the gradient image you want.

Answer (score 1):

A UIToolbar in iOS6 and earlier always draws its shine over the top 22px.  If you want a bigger shine, you'll have to provide a background image using [setBackgroundImage:forToolbarPosition:barMetrics:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIToolbar/setBackgroundImage%3aforToolbarPosition%3abarMetrics%3a).

Two more things, though:

1. UIToolbar on an iPhone expects to be at the bottom of your content; if you're using it to give you a background suitable for the top, you should use a UINavigationBar instead.
2. The appearance of toolbars, navigation bars, and the lock screen has changed in iOS7. You may want to rethink your approach so that your app doesn't look bad in the near future.

Comment: If i use navigation bar instead of toolbar then i cannot increase its height. If i add prompt to navigationbar then i cannot increase its font. So what do you think?

Comment: Since you're just trying to set a particular background, instead of using UIToolbar and UINavigationBar, use a UIImageView for the image, and use UILabel for the text.